# Find solution of $9*16^x + 4*81^x = 13*36^x$

Tags: analysis

So I got to the point where I got $3^2*2^{4x} + 2^2*3^{4x} - 13*2^{2x}*3^{2x} = 0$

Can anyone help me with this equation?

Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can let $m = 9^x$ and $n = 4^x$, the equation will become $$9n^2 - 13 mn + 4m^2 = 0$$

Can you do it from here?